# Automatic script to run django command

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I am using django haystack and i want to make an automatic command that whenever the development server or the real server refreshes it automaticaly runs. . /manage.py update_index. This is to automate things so that i will not have to constantly run the command to index the pages whenever something is posted

Comment: you can create a `post_save` signal on your model. Although it can led to performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/searchindex_api.html#keeping-the-index-fresh) you can use either a Cron Job by setting one to run the update_index command every a couple of minutes/hours or a day. The command should look like this

```
* 1 * * * path/to/env/bin/python /path/to/django-imc/manage.py update_index
```

where /env/bin is the virtualenv folder. This cron job will run every hour

Otherwise Haystack [provides a processor](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signal_processors.html#realtime-realtimesignalprocessor) where anytime the model changes, it automatically updates the index. This can be achieved by appending the following in your settings.py file

```
HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'
```